# Java Email -Tthe messages are joined when I send 2 mail with same subject

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I have problem with Java to send email.

If I send a email to my address with a subject and after I resend another email with same subject, gmail group the messages one under other (like a chat).

I'm using javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage for to make the message, and Trasport.send for sending it.

I have to change some property for separate the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by Gmail - You can set it off

https://wiki.umbc.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1867916

1. Open Gmail.
2. Click the gear in the top right.
3. Select Settings.
4. Scroll down to the Conversation View section (stay in the "General"
       tab).
5. Choose Conversation view on or Conversation view off.
6. Click Savechanges at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yeah, I also checked it. Gmail, when sending from self to self does not group it. Seems like a gmail feature. However when I send multiple emails from an other email, with the same subject, gmail does group it.

Comment: Yes, it's true, I tried to send to another address 2 mail and gmail grouped it. Thank you :)